# split the column into multiple columns with dynamic names and then convert to json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ("REG1","A=1;B=2;C=3"),
        ("REG2","D=1;E=2;F=3"),
    ], 
    columns=["region","split"]
)

print(df)

  region        split
0   REG1  A=1;B=2;C=3
1   REG2  D=1;E=2;F=3

splitdata=df["split"].str.split(';',expand=True)

print(splitdata)
     0    1    2
0  A=1  B=2  C=3
1  D=1  E=2  F=3
```

what i actually want is the name of the split data columns as A, B, C etc and then convert the dataframe into a json output

What i now need to do is to have the column name as

```
    region  A_split    B_split    C_split    D_split    E_split    F_split
0   REG1      1          2          3
1   REG2                                       1           2          3
```

Finally i now want to convert the df to a json as formatted below

```
[
    {
    "region" : REG1
    "record" : REG1*A=1;B=2;C=3*
    "splitdata" :
        {
           "A" : 1,
           "B" : 2,
           "C" : 3
        }
    },
    {
    "region" : REG2
    "record" : REG2*D=1;E=2;F=3*
    "splitdata" :
        {
           "D" : 1,
           "E" : 2,
           "F" : 3
        }
    }
]
```

Here in the json, record is the initial table with the seperator as "*" for each column. Also what is the most efficient way where i need to process thousands of records..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create column `record` for join columns first:

```
df['record'] = df['region'] + '*' + df['split'] + '*'
#alternative for multiple columns
#df['record'] = df[['region','split']].agg('*'.join, axis=1) + '*' 
#alternative for all columns
#df['record'] = df.astype(str).agg('*'.join, axis=1) + '*'
```

Then create `splitdata` for convert splitted values by `;` and `=` to dictionaries:

```
df['splitdata'] = df["split"].apply(lambda x: dict([y.split('=') for y in x.split(';')]))
print (df)
  region        split             record                       splitdata
0   REG1  A=1;B=2;C=3  REG1*A=1;B=2;C=3*  {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}
1   REG2  D=1;E=2;F=3  REG2*D=1;E=2;F=3*  {'D': '1', 'E': '2', 'F': '3'}
```

Last remove `split` column and for `json` use [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
json = df.drop('split', axis=1).to_json(orient='records')
print (json)
[{"region":"REG1","record":"REG1*A=1;B=2;C=3*","splitdata":{"A":"1","B":"2","C":"3"}},
 {"region":"REG2","record":"REG2*D=1;E=2;F=3*","splitdata":{"D":"1","E":"2","F":"3"}}]
```

Another idea for dictionaries by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
di = df.drop('split', axis=1).to_dict(orient='records')
print (di)
[{'region': 'REG1', 'record': 'REG1*A=1;B=2;C=3*', 'splitdata': {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}}, 
 {'region': 'REG2', 'record': 'REG2*D=1;E=2;F=3*', 'splitdata': {'D': '1', 'E': '2', 'F': '3'}}]
```

Comment: Thanks you.. I never explored lambda.. seems powerful.. Also i need to convert the dataframe of 'splitdata'  column into multiple columns to do some predictions later on..